# Obtener texto con letras y números separados por guiones

Tags: java, regex

Tengo expresiones que necesito obtener de un texto. El texto tiene x cantidad de información y necesito extraer la partes del texto que cumplen con un patrón.

Estructura:

- Letras o números hasta 2 o sea PE, N, E , 1, 3, 6 etc
- Luego vendría un guión y combinación de números únicamente de hasta 4 valores
- Luego vendría otro guión y combinación de números únicamente de hasta 4 valores

Quedando por ejemplo:

```
PE-13-641
N-12-1236
1-11-778
```

Utilice este código pero no me está dando resultado:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{2,}|(\\d+)]+\\-)");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(cleanpageone);
mat.find();

for(int i=0; i<mat.groupCount(); i++){
    System.out.println(mat.group(i));
}
```

Nota: Siendo `cleanpageone` el texto general con la información que deseo extraer.

Comment: [`Matcher#groupCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount--) es la cantidad de paréntesis que coincidieron y capturaron texto, no tiene nada que ver con la cantidad de coincidencias. La única forma de contarlas es llamando a `Matcher#find()` hasta que devuelva `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Letras o números hasta 2, guión, números hasta 4, guión, números hasta 4

Expresión regular:

```
\b[A-Z\d]{1,2}(?:-\d{1,4}){2}\b
```

- La idea es usar una [clase de caracteres](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cc) (entre corchetes) que coincida con letras o dígitos `[A-Z\d]`, que coinciden con 1 único caracter, y [repetirla](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) (con un [cuantificador](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy)) entre 1 y 2 veces `[A-Z\d]{1,2}`.
- Lo mismo con el guión y los dígitos, entre 1 y 4 `-\d{1,4}`, pero repetimos todo esto 2 veces (las 2 veces que aparece en el texto) usando un [grupo sin captura](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special), para que el cuantificador aplique tanto al guión como a los 1-4 dígitos: `(?:-\d{1,4}){2}`.
- Encapsulé al regex entre [`\b`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds) ([límites de palabras completas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds)), para que no permita otras letras o dígitos alrededor de una coincidencia.

[image: Visualización de regexper.com]

Código:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```
final String regex = "\\b[A-Z\\d]{1,2}(?:-\\d{1,4}){2}\\b";
final String cleanpageone = "PE-13-641 N-12-1236 1-11-778";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cleanpageone);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Resultado:

```
PE-13-641
N-12-1236
1-11-778
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/D6NDWf